# Add Watcher - Rally Rest API

Tags: rally, code-rally

How to "Add Watcher" using Rally Rest API? I am unable to locate any keywords "watch", "watcher" or reference to watcher in [documentation](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/)

Edit 1:
Based on Joshua's answer
I have tried the below:

```
DynamicJsonObject watcherToBeAdded = new DynamicJsonObject();
DynamicJsonObject watcherResult;
watcherToBeAdded["UserUUID"] = User's UUID;
watcherToBeAdded["ArtifactUUID"] = Story's UUID;
watcherToBeAdded["zuul_key"] = rallyAPIKey;
watcherResult = restApi.Post("notifications/watch", watcherToBeAdded);
```

This led to method not allowed.

I have also tried:

```
string rallyRef = "https://rally1.rallydev.com/notifications/api/v2/watch";
DynamicJsonObject toUpdate = new DynamicJsonObject();
toUpdate["ArtifactUUID"] = StoryUUID;
toUpdate["UserUUID"] = UserUUID;
OperationResult updateResult = restApi.Update(rallyRef, toUpdate);
```

This is throwing the below exception:
Value cannot be null
Parameter name: key

Answer (score 0):

**Authentication**:

All requests to must be authenticated with a valid zsessionid or Rally API Key. You can pass this in a few ways:

As a header: `zuul=[ZSESSIONID]`
or `zuul=[RALLY_API_KEY]`

As a cookie: `ZSESSIONID=[ZSESSIONID]`
or `ZSESSIONID=[RALLY_API_KEY]`

As a query parameter: `zuul_key=[ZSESSIONID]`
or `zuul_key=[RALLY_API_KEY]`

**To add a "watch"**, you can send a request like:

```
Method: POST
Url:    https://rally1.rallydev.com/notifications/api/v2/watch
Body: 
{
  UserUUID: <ObjectUUID of user to be added as watcher,
  ArtifactUUID: <ObjectUUID of artifact to be watched>
}
```

**To remove a watch**, you can send a request like:

```
Method: DELETE
URL: https://rally1.rallydev.com/notifications/api/v2/watch?ArtifactUUID=<ObjectUUID of artifact>&UserUUID=<ObjectUUID of User to remove as watcher>
```

Comment: I have added my code which I am trying. I still couldn't figure out how to solve this. Any help?

Comment: I am getting the below when I try to post via postman. Is the post URL correct?

{
  "Errors": [
    {
      "message": "Invalid User",
      "details": "{:subscription-id 3214, :user-uuid nil}"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Errors like that can happen when you try sending an invalid (expired) ZSESSIONID or invalid API key in your request, can you verify that whichever you are using is passed one of the ways listed above and valid?